# TYPO3 felogin - How do I get a fontawesome icon into a felogin label?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x, felogin

How do I get a fontawesome icon into a felogin label? The below does not work:

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1._LOCAL_LANG.default {
    login = Login
    #login = <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>Login   
}
```

FeloginTemplate.html

```
<div class="loginsubmit">
    <i class="fa fa-sign-in icon-style" title="Login"></i>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="###LOGIN_LABEL###" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Copy the template file in felogin into your site package (or even fileadmin)
2. Set the TypoScript to use your template file `plugin.tx_felogin.templateFile`
3. Change the login directly in the template and add FontAwesome code

Working:

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" name="submit"><i class="fa fa-sign-in icon-style"></i>###LOGIN_LABEL###</button>
```

Comment: ... but when I put it in the template like above ... the fa icon is outside of the button?

Comment: What about using `<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-sign-in icon-style"></i> ###LOGIN_LABEL###</button>`?